# Committed a major sin

Tags: sin

If someone committed a major sin on purpose know that Allah is watching ,and then  feels guilty will Allah  ever forgive that person  and if so how long will that sin stay for

Answer (score 1):

بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
قُلْ يَا عِبَادِيَ الَّذِينَ أَسْرَفُوا عَلَىٰ أَنفُسِهِمْ لَا تَقْنَطُوا مِن رَّحْمَةِ اللَّـهِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ جَمِيعًا ۚ إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحِيمُ

Say: "O my Servants who have transgressed against their souls! Despair not of the Mercy of Allah: for Allah forgives all sins: for He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.

This is a rule, if someone assumes his sin is bigger than Allah's mercy, they he has wrong view of Allah, like those who Allah describe by them having evil opinion about Allah:

> الظَّانِّينَ بِاللَّـهِ ظَنَّ السَّوْءِ ۚ عَلَيْهِمْ دَائِرَةُ
>   السَّوْءِ ۖ وَغَضِبَ اللَّـهُ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَعَنَهُمْ وَأَعَدَّ لَهُمْ
>   جَهَنَّمَ ۖ وَسَاءَتْ مَصِيرًا
>
> who imagine an evil opinion of Allah. On them is a round of Evil: the
>   Wrath of Allah is on them: He has cursed them and got Hell ready for
>   them: and evil is it for a destination

That's why losing hope in Allah's mercy is among the worst of the sins by itself, and maybe the worst altogether:

> لَا تَيْأَسُوا مِن رَّوْحِ اللَّـهِ ۖ إِنَّهُ لَا يَيْأَسُ مِن رَّوْحِ
>   اللَّـهِ إِلَّا الْقَوْمُ الْكَافِرُونَ
>
> never give up hope of Allah's Soothing Mercy: truly no one despairs of
>   Allah's Soothing Mercy, except those who have no faith.

if the person feels sorry, repents and tries to compensate as much as possibe, then he will verily find Allah Oft-returning, most merciful. He can even feel Allah's forgiveness with his soul.